# New to PWA's, need a bit of guidance

Tags: html, progressive-web-apps, manifest

I am trying PWA's for the first time and did a simple tutorial, however, it doesn't appear to want to give me the option to 'install' the app to desktop

probably missed something...
this is the simple PWA code

```
************************************
    /**sw.js**/
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // on install - the application shell cached
    self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open('sw-cache').then(function(cache) {
            //static files that make up the application shell are cached
            return cache.add('index.html');//if you have css file and app.js files
            //please add here as well to be cached! we havent added as we have a simple app
            //but your website uses them
        })
        );
    });
    
    //with request network
    self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
        event.respondWith(
            //try the cache
            caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
                //return it if there is a response, or else fetch again
                return response || fetch(event.request);
            })
        );
    });
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    /**manifest.json**/
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    {
        "short_name": "WD1",
        "name": "Testing PWA",
        "icons": [
            {
                "src": "/images/default-150X131.png",
                "type": "image/png",
                "sizes": "150x150"
            },
            {
                "src": "/images/default-400X200.png",
                "type": "image/png",
                "sizes": "150x 150"
            }
        ],
        "start_url": "/index.html",
        "background_color": "#000000",
        "display": "standalone",
        "theme_color": "#616161"
        }
    
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /**index.html**/
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

<!doctype html>

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge">
<title>Holistic PWA test</title>
<meta name="description" content="Software is feeding the world" />
<meta name="theme-color" content="#213e20" />
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
<script>
    //if browser support sevice worker
    if ('seviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js');
    };
</script>
</head>
```

```
<h1>Welcome to MELP</h1>
<p>this is some text to fill out the demo page</p>
<p>this is some text to fill out the demo page,this is some text to fill out the demo page,this is some text to fill out the demo page</p>
```

************************************

I am just wanting it to add pwa icon to desktop using this demo, before moving onto more in-depth layouts

help appreciated

Comment: Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool? If there are issues, it usually gives good hints.

Comment: I have a free online tool that will scaffold icons, manifest and a skeleton service worker (I don't think you will need the sw it provides). It will general a large set of icons for different browsers and platforms. Also note the meta tags it includes in the index.html.
The criteria keep updating. So older tutorials may not apply today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Chrome (and most other browsers), your icons must include a 192px icon, and a 512px icon. The icons you're supplying don't meet the requirements.

Check out https://web.dev/install-criteria/ for the typical install criteria for PWAs. And, as Mathias recommended, using Lighthouse in Chrome DevTools is a good/easy way to test your app and make sure it meets the PWA criteria.